# NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); Failure

Tags: java, number-formatting

I'm trying to parse my currency string into a bigdecimal using NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

```
The following scenario
$1,000.01 Pass
1000.01 Pass
1,000.01 Fail -> This needs to be parsed to 1000.01 in order to pass.
abc Fail -> correct behavior.
```

My method

```
   public BigDecimal parseClient(Field field, String clientValue, String message) throws ValidationException {
        if (clientValue == null) {
            return null;
        }

        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        try {
            return new BigDecimal(nf.parse(clientValue).toString());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            throw new ValidationException(message);
        }
    }
```

Anybody know of a good solution to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly brute force, but why not just check for the presence of the currency characters at the beginning of the string, and if it is not there, prepend it?

```
if ( !clientValue.startsWith( "$" ) )
{
   clientValue = "$" + clientValue;
}
```

If the brute force approach is not desired, the next approach would be to take note of each format that the client can come into the method.  Then, create as many DecimcalFormat instances that are necessary to handle those incoming input formats -- and allow them to be parsed.

Another approach is to standardize the incoming clientValue into a single format.  This could be done through string manipulation and regex.  However, you still have the issue that you need to know all of the different ways the incoming clientvalue can come into the method.  So requirements are very important here.

Comment: That was my if all else fails solution, I just wasn't sure if there was a more elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: Well, the thing to know about decimal formats (and date formats, too) is that they aren't failsafe for all possible permutations.  For example, what about negative currency?  There's a couple of ways to express that.  What if the negative comes before or after the number?  For things like this, you really have to try to standardize the input coming in.  As opposed to allowing a free-for-all approach to parsing the value.

Comment: @George Another possible way to do this would be to attempt to parse the incoming value with a couple of different DecimalFormats.  Obviously, with the code you wrote, the incoming value could be not only a currency format, but also a standard numerical decimal format, as well.

Comment: Great point, I completely overlooked that scenario. Do you have any suggestions in regards to that? I'm just trying to convert a clientside string to a bigdecimal before being inserted into the db.

Comment: That is correct, both numeric and currency would be appropriate. I'm just uncertain how to handle a negative value now.

Comment: First, I think you need to basically create a format for every format you expect.  In some situations, you will get lucky and one pattern will handle multiple formats of incoming data.  For the exception cases that fail, you really need to create another DecimalFormat that handles those situations.  For negative currency, run a small local test where you format() a negative number into each format.  That will give you an idea of what the acceptable inputs are.

Comment: I'm going to check you off as the best answer since you answered my original question correctly. However after some of the items you pointed out, the best solution is to use regular expressions to strip the characters out. I will post my code.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, that was my second solution a few comments above this was.  Standardize the input coming in.  That certainly can be accomplished using regular expressions.  Just understand that using regular expressions presents the same issue.  You may have to apply more than one regular expression to get the incoming value into a parseable format using a single decimalformat instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this constructor instead:

```
public static NumberFormat getCurrencyInstance(Locale inLocale)
```

Comment: I set the constructor to Locale.US and it still seems to fail.